# using preg_match_all image source with user defined tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

HTML code

```
<img src="http://website/image/ngshjk.jpeg" onload="img_onload(this);" onerror="img_onerror(this);" data-pid="dynamicvalue" data-imagesize="ppew" data-error-url="http://img.comb/6/z2default.jpg" class="small_image imageZoom " alt="image" title="" id="visible-image-small" rel="dynamicvalue" data-zoom-src="http://img.comb/6/z21347.jpeg" style="display: inline;">
```

PHP code

```
preg_match_all('/<img(.*) onload="(.*)" \/s',$con,$val);
```

Already this page have so many img tag. so I tried to get the src of particular image using some attributes inside the img tag. i cannot be correct in preg_match_all. please correct me in getting source in the above img tag.

Comment: How is this desired image tag special and different from all the others?

Comment: @Denomales thats why i'm unable to do. i'm sure other img tag dont have  onload="img_onload(this);"

Comment: Would it be best to simply find all the image tags as a list then later in your code, simply review them to find the ones which are interesting?

Answer (score 3):

You might be better off using the lazy `.*?` instead of the greedy `.*`.

```
preg_match_all('/<img(.*?)\sonload="([^"]*)"/s',$con,$val);
```

And change the second `.*` to `[^"]*` instead.

`.*?` matches the least number of characters until the next match (in this case `onload...`) and `[^"]*` matches any non quotes characters in between the quotes.

Comment: @MohamedFawaskhan Do you want to get the src attribute as well? If so, you could use `<img\ssrc="([^"]*)"\sonload="([^"]*)"`. Otherwise, I'm afraid I don't understand what you're trying to do with the regex. You might as well find an HTML parser instead of regex since html can be very volatile.

Answer (score 0):

## Description

This expression will:

- validate the image tag has attribute/value of `data-imagesize="ppew"`
- validate the image tag has attribute/value of `data-pid="ABCDEFGHIJ"`
- capture the `src` attribute value
- avoid potentially difficult problems

.

```
<img\b(?=\s) # capture the open tag
(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\sdata-imagesize="ppew")  # validate data-imagesize exists with a specific value
(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\sdata-pid="ABCDEFGHIJ")  # validate data-pid exists with a specific value
(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\ssrc=['"]([^"]*)['"]?)  # capture the src attribute value
(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"\s]*)*"\s?\/?> # get the entire  tag
```

[image]

## Examples

Live Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/PBJ50cax7L

Single Line Regex: `<img\b(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\sdata-imagesize="ppew")(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\sdata-pid="ABCDEFGHIJ")(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\ssrc=['"]([^"]*)['"]?)(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"\s]*)*"\s?\/?>`

**Sample Text**

Note the first line has some potentially problematic conditions

```
<img onmouseover=' data-imagesize="ppew" ; data-pid="ABCDEFGHIJ" ; funSwap(data-imagesize, data-pid) ; ' src="http://website/NotTheDroidYourLookingFor.jpeg" onload="img_onload(this);" onerror="img_onerror(this);" data-pid="jihgfedcba" data-imagesize="ppew" />
<img src="http://website/someurl.jpeg" onload="img_onload(this);" onerror="img_onerror(this);" data-pid="ABCDEFGHIJ" data-imagesize="ppew" />
```

**Capture Groups**

```
[0] = <img src="http://website/someurl.jpeg" onload="img_onload(this);" onerror="img_onerror(this);" data-pid="ABCDEFGHIJ" data-imagesize="ppew" />
[1] = http://website/someurl.jpeg
```

Comment: i'm weak in creating expressions but i can understand your codes. i edited my question please have a look now.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the image tags on the page it would probably be much easier to use an HTML parsing tool like:

```
// load your html string
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($your_html_here);


// find all the img tags
$imgs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

// cycle through all image tags
foreach($imgs as $img) {
    $src = $img->getAttribute("src");
    // do something
}
```